# Warning: session_start(): open(/var/www/temp

Tags: php, session

I am getting a php warning on my session_start(). You can see the functional code [here](http://runnable.com/UtEZ4OpSEoFzAACs/quickbooks-oauth-%2B-list-customers-example-for-php-intuit-and-intuit-partner-platform)

I am trying to set the temp directory to a directory with write permissions (chmod 777 temp) and it works. However, after the project is published with runnable the permissions for the temp directory is lost.

So other runnable examples seem to work, why is it that mine does not?

Here is the full error for reference: Warning: session_start(): open(/var/www/temp/sess_mgavllqdlnl36argo108k4d1p6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/index.php on line 3

Comment: I'm new to runnable, but that looks great and it's cool that you've contributed this. That all being said, I'm unfamiliar with how you define a directory structure @ runnable. At what point is /var/www/temp created? Also, I recommend you put the `require_once("./config.php");` directive at the very top of index.php, before any output is sent.

Comment: @Charlie - there is a little folder on the right hand side of the code and you can work on the files and folders from there.  If you are comfortable with command line you can edit everything in command line as well which is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Interesting. I tried out http://runnable.com/UobuRXxMTRlWAAAJ/write-to-a-file-in-php# and it works fine to create a new file. I also threw random `mkdir('foo');` lines in there and they work as well. Does this problem occur with a new project?

Comment: @charlie - I took your code and ran it in Web Only and it had permission errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that with the way aufs works, permissions can't be upgraded (it's more complicated than that, but for effectively that's how it is right now).

We've created a new base php project with the file permissions fixed.

If you fork off of http://runnable.com/UobuRXxMTRlWAAAJ/write-to-a-file-in-php things should work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like theres something a bit off with runnable. When you click the arrow next to "run" you have a few options:

[image: run options]

Anything that runs through "Web" (even if done through "Web & Terminal") doesn't have write permission. Anything run through terminal does.

Change the run type to "Web & Terminal" and see if you get issues then. Here's an example:

**Code**

[image]

**Web**

[image]

**Terminal**

[image]

My only advice is to open a ticket or otherwise contact runnable.com with this. Alternatively, you can just show output to users via terminal.

Comment: In this example it needs to run in the web mode so a popup can show and the oAuth process execute. I submitted a ticket with runnable so I guess it is in their hands.  I was hoping there was an apache or server config that I might update.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: For the php examples we have apache running as www-data, when you run the command in the terminal or as the run command it runs as root. As a note all the config is in the env. -- Henry from runnable.com

Comment: @generalhenry I wouldn't want Apache to run as anything other than www-data, so would there be a way to create a folder in a project that has more liberal write permissions and have it persist?

Comment: The permission persistence issue is caused by our use of aufs, aufs doesn't permit new layers to loosen file permissions on existing files.  We're still looking into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start` must be called before ***any*** output is sent, such as your `<html>` and head stuff.

Comment: I tried putting session_start() at the top of index.php and the error continued to occur.

Comment: actually, it might be... line 25 of index.php looks like it is including the config file there, which is after HTML and would throw an error - but your error looks like your `session_save_path` is a folder you don't have permission for. Why are you setting the save path?

Comment: The problem doesn't have to do with the output being sent.

Comment: @scrowler - when it was not set i was also getting a permissions error. So I started setting a location then changing the permissions to 777 for it to work.  That fix "does work" but after a publish the permissions on the folder don't publish correctly so the error pops up again.  However, it does seem like sessions work for other php examples. I am simply not sure what they are doing different, or what I am doing wrong.